# Can AWS Lambda be used to host Gembox.Document (a C#/VB.Net component), and expose it as a utility API for applications to leverage?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am assessing the choice of AWS Lambda, to host [Gembox.Document](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document) as a utility service that other applications can invoke via a REST API. Is that feasible, or not the best use of AWS stack? Ideally consumer clients send merge data via REST API, and the AWS function leverages Gembox.Document to process and return merged file, as response.

Comment: I'd try it - it doesn't look like it would be too hard to get setup.  As you'll likely have to use API Gateway in front, realize that you are limited to a 10MB payload size.  The files you're dealing with very well may be bigger than that.  If you really need that then Lambda isn't the right choice.  A small EC2 may be better.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invoke a Lambda function using Rest, then you can use API Gateway. This lets you setup methods such as GET methods that can invoke your Lambda function and return data. Using API GateWay to accept Restful requests, invoking a Lambda function and then returning data is a valid way to setup AWS Solutions. For more information, see this doc topic:

[Build an API Gateway REST API with Lambda integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-lambda-integration.html)

And you can create Lambda functions using .NET/C#.

Comment: Thank you @smac2020 or the validation. I have also been reading up topics around this. Looks like I would also need to keep in mind the fact that Lambda may go to sleep. If I am to keep the api (and service) alive at all times, I suppose I have to introduce a hack using CloudWatch events to keep Lambda alive?